# Update python version from 2.6.5 to 2.7.9 in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-2.x

In one of the remote computers i'm using there's a python version of 2.6.5
and I want to upgrade it to 2.7.9.
It is currently located under C:\Python26 .

I need to upgrade it in such way that will direct the PATH to the newer python (meaning when I will write in command line "python " it will use the newer version.

Regards,
Matan

Comment: The Python installer should do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

On windows (and Nix machines) you can do this by modifying Path variable. 
On Windows 7:

Right-click `Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables-> System Variables -> Path`.

Modify this variable to add path to your new Python installation dir. Example:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;<existing path>...
```

Close and reopen all your CMD and Powershell windows, and type in `python -V`. You should see your new Python version pop up.

Comment: This won't work. You need to add `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts` to the **beginning** of the `PATH`, not the end.

Comment: It can be at the end, but any reference to Python26 should be removed.